# PHP - Get combinations from array

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

I need an advice, how to create tree view from folowing source.

```
$dataSrc = array(
 '1@02@43@170@1',
 '1@02@43@176@1',
 '1@02@43@182@1',
 '1@02@42@182@1',
 '1@02@42@176@1',
);
```

This strings are grouped variants of product. Each parameter is separated by @. So if I explode this strings I will get theese.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 43
            [3] => 170
            [4] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 43
            [3] => 176
            [4] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 43
            [3] => 182
            [4] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 42
            [3] => 182
            [4] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 02
            [2] => 42
            [3] => 176
            [4] => 1
        )

)
```

Now I need to get combinations for parameters, which is not same. Result should be:

```
$resp = array(
  43 => array(
     170,
     176,
     182,
    ),
  42 => array(
     182,
     176,
   )
);
```

So unset keys, which are same and get tree from cobninations. Can you please help me with that?

Additional details (edited into question from OP's comments -- some of which were deleted):

> These strings (1@02@43@170@1) are combined variants of products (returned from external DB) 1 - some param 02 - color 43 - sizeA 178 - sizeB Each product is available in specific combinations, which are declared by these strings. So if I will have 1@02@43@170@1 and 1@02@43@176@1 it means that i have product with size 43 and in size 43 I have another variants 176 and 170. It's really hard to explain, but i need these values grouped.

> I do not know which values are different. First of all, I need to know what parameters need to be grouped (it can be for example two or three params).

> if values are same, it should not be grouped. If there will be 3 different values, it should be like that: $final = array( '02' => array( 42 => array( 170, 176, ), 43 => array( 182, 176, ), ), '03' => array( 42 => array( 170, 176, ), ) );

> It should be grouped hierarchical, so first different value at parent level.

Another possible sample set:

```
$dataSrc2 = array(
    '1@02@43@170@1',
    '1@02@43@176@1',
    '1@02@43@182@1',
    '1@02@42@182@1',
    '1@02@42@176@1',
    '1@03@43@170@1',
    '1@03@43@176@1',
    '1@03@43@182@1',
    '1@03@42@182@1',
    '1@03@42@176@1',
);
```

Comment: Question is not making sense. How did you derive that output?

Comment: These strings (1@02@43@170@1) are combined variants of products (returned from external DB)

1 - some param
02 - color
43 - sizeA
178 - sizeB

Each product is available in specific combinations, which are declared by these strings. So if I will have 1@02@43@170@1 and 1@02@43@176@1 it means that i have product with size 43 and in size 43 I have another variants 176 and 170. It's really hard to explain, but i need these values grouped.

Comment: Ok, why `182` isn't there in key `43`?

Comment: Sorry typo. It should be in 43. I have fixed it in question.

Comment: So, it is group by based on first 3 values `1 | 02 | 43` as they uniquely define a product?

Comment: it is based of values which are different. Please see examples here https://justpaste.it/1ws2x. The input string has variable count of parameters

Comment: The justpaste site is not loading. Paste it elsewhere.

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/DkjU88R3Bt

Comment: Ok, so you want the last one in that which has a hierarchy of data like 1 => 02 => 43 => (170,172,183) etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing the array of `@`-delimited strings into a nested structure with a known depth, you are seeking a lean output array of unknown depth whereby the top level has more than one entry.

To accomplish this, my code below will parse the strings into the limited-depth array structure, then recursively strip away the top level(s) if there is only one entry.  The resulting array will either be an empty array (if all strings are identical) or it will have a top level with multiple entries.

Code: ([Demo with 3 sample sets](https://3v4l.org/H0IhR))

```
function killYourParentIfYouHaveOne($level) {
    if (count($level) === 1) {
         $key = key($level);
         $level = is_array($level[$key]) ? killYourParentIfYouHaveOne($level[$key]) : [];
    }
    return $level;
}

function differingTree(array $array): array {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        [$a, $b, $c, $d, $e] = explode('@', $item, 5);
        $result[$a][$b][$c][$d] = $e;
    }
    return killYourParentIfYouHaveOne($result);
}

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo var_export(differingTree($test), true) . "\n---\n";
}
```

Sample Inputs:

```
$tests = [
    [
        '1@02@43@170@1',
        '1@02@43@176@1',
        '1@02@43@182@1',
        '1@02@42@182@1',
        '1@02@42@176@1',
    ],
    [
        '1@02@43@170@1',
        '1@02@43@176@1',
        '1@02@43@182@1',
        '1@02@42@182@1',
        '1@02@42@176@1',
        '1@03@43@170@1',
        '1@03@43@176@1',
        '1@03@43@182@1',
        '1@03@42@182@1',
        '1@03@42@176@1',
    ],
    [
        '1@02@43@170@1',
        '1@02@43@170@1',
    ]
];
```

Generated Outputs:

```
array (
  43 => 
  array (
    170 => '1',
    176 => '1',
    182 => '1',
  ),
  42 => 
  array (
    182 => '1',
    176 => '1',
  ),
)
---
array (
  '02' => 
  array (
    43 => 
    array (
      170 => '1',
      176 => '1',
      182 => '1',
    ),
    42 => 
    array (
      182 => '1',
      176 => '1',
    ),
  ),
  '03' => 
  array (
    43 => 
    array (
      170 => '1',
      176 => '1',
      182 => '1',
    ),
    42 => 
    array (
      182 => '1',
      176 => '1',
    ),
  ),
)
---
array (
)
---
```

Answer (score 0):

> Firstly check your exploded data is not empty
>
>  Have an array that will display the output, in our case say $ans
>
>  keep the first index of the array as first element of your exploded data
>
>  As you have your pivot in index 2 and value in index 3, we initialize our answer array as explodedarray's[0][2] < 2 because of your pivot
>
>  Now in your loop check if the index is already created, if not then create it. in our case we have already 42 as created so when it gets into the loop it wont create 42 for the first time, but when it sees 43 our isset() function will return false and our code will create a new index for our $ans array 
>
>  Once this index creation is done you simply need to add in your [3] (as in our case this index is your value ) index to the current $ans array

```
<?php
        $dataSrc = array(
         '1@02@43@170@1',
         '1@02@43@176@1',
         '1@02@43@182@1',
         '1@02@42@182@1',
         '1@02@42@176@1',
        );
        
        $arr = array();
        foreach($dataSrc as $d)
        {
            
        $x[] = explode('@',$d); 
        }
        
        if(!empty($x))
        {
            $ans = array();
            $ans[$x[0][2]] = array();
            foreach($x as $dp)
            {
                if(!isset($ans[$dp[2]]))
                {
                    $ans[$dp[2]] = array();
                }
                $ans[$dp[2]][] = $dp[3];
            }
            
        }
        
        dd($ans)
```

Comment: @mickmackusa my bad, thanks for correcting. I have added description now. cheers

Comment: You cannot see deleted comments yet, so I'll show you that the OP needs a more dynamic solution.  c4ni said: `Yes, if values are same, it should not be grouped. If there will be 3 different values, it should be like that: $final = array( '02' => array( 42 => array( 170, 176, ), 43 => array( 182, 176, ), ), '03' => array( 42 => array( 170, 176, ), ) );`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see from your problem, it needs only 2nd, 3rd and 4th element of the structure in each data set, i tried to give a solution by accessing the index of that datasets elements.

```
$dataSrc = [
   [
   '1@02@43@170@1',
   '1@02@43@176@1',
   '1@02@43@182@1',
   '1@02@42@182@1',
   '1@02@42@176@1',
   '1@03@43@170@1',
   '1@03@43@176@1',
   '1@03@43@182@1',
   '1@03@42@182@1',
   '1@03@42@176@1',
   ],
   [ 
   '1@02@43@170@1',
   '1@02@43@176@1',
   '1@02@43@182@1',
   '1@02@42@182@1',
   '1@02@42@176@1',
   ]


];

$result = [];
 
foreach ($dataSrc as $input_data ) {
   $result [] = process_input( $input_data );
}

var_dump( $result );


function process_input( $input_data )
{
   $data = [];
   array_walk( $input_data, function ( $each_row ) use ( &$data )
   {
      $data[] =  explode('@', $each_row);
   });
  
   $processed = [];
   
   foreach ($data as $value) {
      $processed [ $value[1] ] [ $value[2] ][] = (int) $value[3];
   }

   return (\count($processed ) === 1) ? array_pop( $processed ) : $processed;
   
}
```